# how can I generate this list of data with a SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

| year | month |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 |
| 2021 | 2 |
| 2021 | 3 |
| 2021 | 4 |
| 2021 | 5 |
| 2021 | 6 |
| 2021 | 7 |
| 2021 | 8 |
| 2021 | 9 |
| 2021 | 10 |
| 2021 | 11 |
| 2021 | 12 |
| 2022 | 1 |
| 2022 | 2 |
| 2022 | 3 |
| 2022 | 4 |
| 2022 | 5 |
| 2022 | 6 |
| 2022 | 7 |
| 2022 | 8 |
| 2022 | 9 |
| 2022 | 10 |
| 2022 | 11 |
| 2022 | 12 |

I can get one column fine, for example
`SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,12) as month`
but I can't find how to get another column next to it that is generated rather than joined to an actual table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a cross join:

```sql
SELECT y.year, m.month
FROM (SELECT 2020 + generate_series(1, 2) AS year) y
CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series(1, 12) AS month) m
ORDER BY y.year, m.month;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 4):

Create a list of dates one for each month:

```
select extract(year from dt) as "year",
       extract(month from dt) as "month"
from generate_series(date '2021-01-01', 
                     date '2022-12-31', 
                     interval '1 month') as g(dt)
order by g.dt;
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I was editing my post

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select
    extract(year from d) "year", 
    extract(month from d) "month"
from generate_series ('2021-01-01', '2022-12-01', interval '1 month') as d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement

```
Select year.*,
   CASE 
       WHEN year = 2021 THEN generate_series(1,12)
       WHEN year = 2022 THEN generate_series(1,12)
   END as month
from generate_series(2021,2022) as year
```

Answer (score 0):

Using integer arithmetic

```
select 2021 + m / 12 "year", m % 12 + 1 "month"
from generate_series(0, 23) as m
```